# T4MVC Url.Action(MVC.Area.Controller.Action()) returns null

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, t4mvc

I'm trying get URL using `Url.Action()` and T4MVC. But this method returns `null`:

```
Url.Action(result:MVC.Data.Persons.Search())
```

how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why it's happening but this was my Area's default route:

```
context.MapRoute(
    "Data_default",
    "Data/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
   MVC.Data.Persons.Persons()
);
```

and that also made `Data` area inaccessible so I rolled back to non-T4MVC mode and both problems solved!